# Accessing a struct defined in another c file?

Tags: c, abstract-class, abstract-data-type

I am trying to access a struct defined in one c file from another c file. The issue is that **I cannot use the `extern` keyword** **nor can I defined the struct in the header file**. How do I access the struct defined in `abstract.c` inside `use_abstract.c`? Here is a minimally producible example:

abstract.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s_strukt {
    int x;
} strukt;

strukt* create_struct() {
    strukt* s = malloc(sizeof(strukt));

    return s;
}
```

abstract.h

```
#ifndef H_ABSTRACT
#define H_ABSTRACT
struct s_strukt;

#endif
```

use_abstract.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "abstract.h"

int main() {

    strukt *s = create_struct();
    s->x = 0;

    return 0;
}
```

Executing the following results in errors `gcc use_abstract.c abstract.c`:

```
use_abstract.c:6:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'strukt'; did you mean 'struct'?
    strukt *s = create_struct();
    ^~~~~~
    struct
use_abstract.c:6:5: error: declaration of anonymous struct must be a definition
use_abstract.c:6:5: warning: declaration does not declare anything [-Wmissing-declarations]
use_abstract.c:7:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 's'
    s->x = 0;
    ^
1 warning and 3 errors generated.
```

Comment: Why can't you use the `extern` keyword?

Comment: It is just a criterion. I am trying solve an issue in my programming book, to teach myself C programming. However I do not believe the above will work and that is why I am asking.

Comment: The `extern` keyword is not relevant here.  It does not apply to types.  Moreover, it is the default for functions and objects declared at file scope.  Explicitly declaring a file-scope *variable* `extern` nevertheless does serve a purpose, but there are no such variables in the code presented.

Comment: @pointersarehard "*trying solve an issue in my programming book*" It's unlikely that any (serious) programming book exercise would require you use an unknown and inaccessible struct. This smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and it would be better if you stated the actual problem you are trying to solve, since this is probably not the right solution.

Comment: @mkrieger1 Can I improve this question in any way? I am unable to ask further questions because this post has 0 up votes.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Can I improve this question in any way? I am unable to ask further questions because this post has 0 up votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways of tackling this particular issue, depending on what you're trying to do.

First, your code seems to be conflating the structure name `struct s_strukt` with the typedef name `strukt`. In general, the `typedef` would live in `abstract.h`, where it would be available to both client code and to the implementation in `abstract.c` (and I think that, in general, having a type name that is one letter different from -- and pronounced the same -- as an existing C keyword is going to lead to confusion and dismay).

If your goal is clear separation between interface and implementation, you can use what are called "[opaque structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type)". This is what you get when you have a type that references a structure the definition of which isn't visible to the calling code (for example, the `FILE` type used by `fopen/fclose/read/write`, etc).

In `abstract.h`, you would have:

```
#ifndef H_ABSTRACT
#define H_ABSTRACT

typedef struct s_strukt strukt;

strukt *create_strukt(void);
#endif
```

And in `abstract.c`, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "abstract.h"

struct s_strukt {
    int x;
};

strukt *create_strukt() {
    strukt *s = malloc(sizeof(strukt));
    return s;
}
```

Given the above, you could write `use_abstract.c` like this and it would compile without error:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "abstract.h"

int main() {
    strukt *s = create_strukt();

    return 0;
}
```

But there's a problem! Because `strukt` is an opaque type, if you try to do this in `use_abstract.c`:

```
s->x = 0;
```

It will fail:

```
use_abstract.c: In function ‘main’:
use_abstract.c:8:6: error: invalid use of incomplete typedef ‘strukt’ {aka ‘struct s_strukt’}
    8 |     s->x = 0;
      |      ^~
```

A typical solution for this is to implement routines in `abstract.c` to get/set values in the opaque structure.  E.g., make `abstract.h` look like this:

```
#ifndef H_ABSTRACT
#define H_ABSTRACT

typedef struct s_strukt strukt;

strukt *create_strukt(void);
void strukt_set_x(strukt *s, int value);
int strukt_get_x(strukt *s);

#endif
```

And `abstract.c` look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "abstract.h"

struct s_strukt {
    int x;
};

strukt *create_strukt() {
    strukt *s = malloc(sizeof(strukt));
    return s;
}

void strukt_set_x(strukt *s, int x) {
    s->x = x;
}

int strukt_get_x(strukt *s) {
    return s->x;
}
```

And then write `use_abstract.c` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "abstract.h"

int main() {
    int val;

    strukt *s = create_strukt();
    strukt_set_x(s, 0);
    val = strukt_get_x(s);
    printf("val is: %d\n", val);

    return 0;
}
```

---

But what if you don't want to use an opaque structure?  Then you would write `abstract.h` like this:

```
#ifndef H_ABSTRACT
#define H_ABSTRACT

typedef struct s_strukt {
    int x;
} strukt;

strukt *create_strukt(void);

#endif
```

Because the structure definition is now in `abstract.h`, where it's exposed both to the implementation in `abstract.c` and the client code in `use_abstract.c`, we no longer need getter/setter functions, because code in `use_abstract.c` can access structure members directly.  With the above, `abstract.c` would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "abstract.h"

strukt *create_strukt() {
    strukt *s = malloc(sizeof(strukt));
    return s;
}
```

And `use_abstract.c` would look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "abstract.h"

int main() {
    strukt *s = create_strukt();
    s->x = 0;
    printf("x is: %d\n", s->x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Amazing answer and just what I was looking for. What you wrote is exatly what I was thinking but was hesitant because it seemed like I was missing something. The restrictions are too narrow in my programming book question (no getter, no setter, no extern, no header definition only header declaration, and so on.) Thanks for your help, you are a life saver!